# Ajax не отправляет данные

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$('.delete_art_button').on('click', function(){
         var this_tab_li = $( ".delete_art_button" ).index( $( this ) );

         var isСonfirm = confirm("Вы хотите удалить статью " + name_article[this_tab_li] + "?");
         var url = '../pages/profil.php';
            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: url,
               data: {confirm: isСonfirm}
            });
   });
```

Вот код, но он не работает. Думаю name_article[this_tab_li] вам знать не нужно (он просто хранит название статьи), незнаю что тут не так(

Comment: "но он не работает" - компьютерный гном сказал?

Comment: ссылку на php скрипт замените на формат: https:// namesite.net/namedir/file.php

Comment: Вы вообще заходите в событие `click`? Если да, то ок, добавьте обработчики в сам `ajax` `success: function (data) { successFunction(data); },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { errorFunction(); }`, в колбэках законсольте ответ, если ответа нет, то вам подсказали верно, дело в урле.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню в ajax, параметр url не зря называется так, вы пытаетесь передать туда путь файловой системы

Comment: Не, вроде путь к обработчику просто.

Comment: неа не работает ввел так - "http://sait/pages/profil.php?login=Top". 
URL ввел (я пытался по разному но не выходило не думаю что проблема в URL)

Comment: я перебробывал кучу вариантов урл но я так и не смог найти правильный(